# pandas dataframe create new rows by iterating through a variable list

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I am new to pandas and am trying to create a new dataframe that adds new rows x number of times based on the length of a list, paired with the sequential value in the list.

I have input data like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 12,13,14 |
| 3 | 254,255 |

and I want to get this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 254 |
| 3 | 255 |

Is this possible with pandas? I have can use a loop but how can I match the repeated A values with each sequential value in B? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: `df.assign(B=df['B'].str.split(',')).explode('B')`